# How to restart browser with Capybara on every scenario?

Tags: ruby, selenium, cucumber, capybara

I run tests using Cucumber in conjunction with Capybara and Selenium-Webdriver. I want restart browser after each scenario. Here is my [env.rb](https://gist.github.com/d3ZoRg/b913fb13576ba263c626). I can add in **After** section something like this:

```
After do |scenario|
  onError scenario if scenario.failed?
  page.driver.browser.close
end
```

but this kills browser after first scenario passed and all other scenarios failed with reasonable error:

```
Errno::ECONNREFUSED: Connection refused - connect(2) for "127.0.0.1" port 7055
```

Is there way to refactor my env.rb to use **Before** [hook](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/wiki/Hooks) to start browser on every scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple:

```
Before do
  Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, :browser => :firefox, :profile => profile)
end
```